# pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: ': not all arguments converted during string formatting Python pandas SQL Error

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I have a following issue. I would like to send df to MySQL database. See my code:

```py
data = {'book_url': ['Tom'],
                'book_id': [20],
                'book_name': ['foo'],
                'book_author': ['foo'],
                'book_rating': ['foo'],
                'book_reviews': ['foo'],
                'book_year': ['foo'],
                'book_description': ['foo'],
                'book_genre': ['foo']
                }

# Create DataFrame
my_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

my_df.to_sql("KNIHY", self.connection, if_exists="append", index=False)
self.connection.commit()
```

My table `KNIHY` is created using:

```py
query = """
        CREATE TABLE KNIHY (book_url TEXT, book_id TEXT, book_name TEXT, book_author 
        TEXT, book_rating TEXT, book_reviews TEXT, 
        book_year TEXT, book_description TEXT, book_genre TEXT)
        """
self.cursor.execute(query)
```

But I got this Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vojtam/Desktop/greads_scrape/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 2056, in execute
    cur.execute(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vojtam/Desktop/greads_scrape/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 146, in execute
    query = self.mogrify(query, args)
  File "/home/vojtam/Desktop/greads_scrape/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 125, in mogrify
    query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vojtam/Desktop/greads_scrape_prod/scrape_prehled.py", line 268, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/vojtam/Desktop/greads_scrape_prod/scrape_prehled.py", line 237, in main
    db.vlozit_df(df_vysledek)
  File "/home/vojtam/Desktop/greads_scrape_prod/db.py", line 81, in vlozit_df
    my_df.to_sql("KNIHY", self.connection, if_exists="append", index=False)
  File "/home/vojtam/Desktop/greads_scrape/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2872, in to_sql
    sql.to_sql(
  File "/home/vojtam/Desktop/greads_scrape/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 717, in to_sql
    pandas_sql.to_sql(
  File "/home/vojtam/Desktop/greads_scrape/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 2225, in to_sql
    table.create()
  File "/home/vojtam/Desktop/greads_scrape/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 856, in create
    if self.exists():
  File "/home/vojtam/Desktop/greads_scrape/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 840, in exists
    return self.pd_sql.has_table(self.name, self.schema)
  File "/home/vojtam/Desktop/greads_scrape/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 2236, in has_table
    return len(self.execute(query, [name]).fetchall()) > 0
  File "/home/vojtam/Desktop/greads_scrape/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 2068, in execute
    raise ex from exc
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': not all arguments converted during string formatting

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried to convert all column to string, but it did not help:

```py
for column in my_df:
   my_df[column] = my_df[column].astype("string")
```

I connect to the db using:

```py
from configparser import ConfigParser
import pymysql as mysql

config = ConfigParser()
config.read("config_knihy.ini")
self.connection = mysql.connect(
                user=config["knihy"]["user"],
                passwd=config["knihy"]["password"],
                host=config["knihy"]["host"],
                db=config["knihy"]["database"],
            )
self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
query = """
        CREATE TABLE KNIHY (book_url TEXT, book_id TEXT, book_name 
        TEXT, book_author TEXT, book_rating TEXT, book_reviews TEXT, 
        book_year TEXT, book_description TEXT, book_genre TEXT)
        """
self.cursor.execute(query)
```

What does that mean please?

Comment: just guessing, try '20' instead of 20

Comment: @EzerK nope, that did not help. Btw, all columns are type of 'object'. Could that be a problem?

Comment: What is the connection object? It is best if you use sqlalchemy, which is an interface on top of database.

Comment: I see nothing wrong in the code/data.

Comment: @BorutFlis I connect to db using `pymysql`. See my edit

Comment: Try sqlalchemy  create_engine.

Comment: from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine("mysql://user:password@127.0.0.1:3306/mydb")

Comment: @BorutFlis this solution will require 'MySQLdb' package which is not possible to install on XUbuntu I guess?

Comment: I think you can use pymysql

Comment: create_engine("mysql+pymysql://user:password@127.0.0.1:3306/mydb")

Comment: @BorutFlis Thanks, that seems to work. However, after `engine = create_engine(f"mysql+pymysql://{user}:{passwd}@{host}/{db}")` i try `con = engine.connect()` and `my_df.to_sql("KNIHY", con=con, if_exists="append", index=False)`. There is no need to commit() ? Something like `con.commit()` gives `AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'commit'`

Comment: I think the commit is done automatically, let me check.

Comment: yes it is auto. You don't need to call commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas .to_sql is meant to be used with SQLAlchemy, which is a DB interface.

```
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://user:password@127.0.0.1:3306/mydb")

my_df.to_sql("KNIHY", engine, if_exists="append", index=False)
```

The inserts are commited automatically.